# Outlook 2007/2010: search query to find all email that one at least one recipient from outside my corporate domain?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search, windows-search

I’m trying to find all the emails that I sent to people outside my employer's domain (say xyz.com).  I need a search query in Outlook that will find all email in the Sent Items folder that has at least one xyz.com recipient?

I tried to create a rule via this post but I didn't get very far:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheThreeMostImportantOutlookRulesForProcessingMail.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a search add-in called [Lookeen](http://www.lookeen.net). Just performed a test search for *.aol.com and the results show all mails containing this domain. I guess that should work for the built-in search as well?! I do recommend trying Lookeen, if you rely on getting information out of mails or any Outlook data fast. There also is a feature they called Lookeen Analytics, which gives me further insight to email communication and some more or less useful statistics... :)

Comment: I want to find all email sent to any domain other than *xyz.com.  Trying *.aol.com then hotmail.com and so on would take too long.

Comment: ... This so reads like an advert!

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do:

1. Open Outlook and click on "Sent Items" folder
2. Click in the Search dialog box, the ribbon should automatically change to "Search tools" layout. Alternatively, in the "Home" layout of the ribbon you can click on "Filter mail" in the "Find" section an select "More Filters..."
3. Click on "Search Tools" icon and select "Advanced Find"
4. Click of the "Advanced" tab
5. Click on the "Field" drop-down list under "Define more criteria" section
6. Select "All Mail fields" -> "To"
7. Under "Condition" select "does not contain"
8. Under "Value" type your company domain
9. Click "Find now"

This should retrieve all emails sent to all domains except your company's

Comment: And i'm not sure about Outlook 2007/2010, but in 2013 you can save your search parameters as a folder inside special "Search Folders" folder and have you query dynamically update itself every time you open it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way might just be to get a tracking report of all outbound mail from the user at your mailgateway.  I ran into the same thing and using the advanced search like above didn't work out since internal from/to addresses aren't the full email address.

Comment: This seems more like a comment then an answer